# What is meaning of the following line in NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm init -y
```

I'm using above line to create node package.json file for my node project using Node Package Manager. But I want to know about `-y`.

What does it do?

Comment: Did you try reading [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)?

Comment: -y stands for --yes

Comment: `Generate it without having it ask any questions`, according to the documentation link of @CertainPerformance.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Now I read it. Thank for the link. I'm naive to node.

Comment: `npm init -y` Will generate `package.json` without asking any question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will run `init` command with this flag you will get default `package.json` file. Take a look at [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json#2-create-a-default-packagejson).

Answer (score 0):

If the initializer is omitted (by just calling npm init), init will fall back to legacy init behavior. It will ask you a bunch of questions, and then write a package.json for you. It will attempt to make reasonable guesses based on existing fields, dependencies, and options selected. It is strictly additive, so it will keep any fields and values that were already set. You can also use -y/--yes to skip the questionnaire altogether. If you pass --scope, it will create a scoped package.

> read doc here. here already mentioned all the things about npm init

[npm init doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)